# Printing a set of words in reverse order

Tags: java, string, reverse

SO I'm doing this assignment for my CSCI class and I can't wrap my brain around ho to do what it needs me to do. Heres part of what the assignment says: "Prompt the user for Pez colors/flavors and then store them in an array or array-like structure.  Dispense the colors/flavors in reverse order"
And heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PezDispenser {

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String col1;
        String col2;
        String col3;
        String col4;
        String col5;
        String col6;
        String col7;
        String col8;
        String col9;
        String col10;

System.out.println("I need ten colors or favors");

        col1 = input.nextInt();
        col2 = input.nextInt();
        col3 = input.nextInt();
        col4 = input.nextInt();
        col5 = input.nextInt();
        col6 = input.nextInt();
        col7 = input.nextInt();
        col8 = input.nextInt();
        col9 = input.nextInt();
        col10 = input.nextInt();

String[] myArray = new String[] {col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 + col6 + col7 + col8 + col9 + col10}; 


System.out.println("Now to dispense");

System.out.println(myArray.asList.reverse(myArray));
}
```

}

Problem is that this only works with numbers, typing a letter in crashes the program.

Comment: You need `nextLine()` or `next()` for `Strings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Problem is that this only works with numbers, typing a letter in
>   crashes the program.**

The program is crashing when you are typing strings is because of this line:

```
col1 = input.nextInt();
col2 = input.nextInt();
col3 = input.nextInt();
col4 = input.nextInt();
col5 = input.nextInt();
col6 = input.nextInt();
col7 = input.nextInt();
col8 = input.nextInt();
col9 = input.nextInt();
col10 = input.nextInt();
```

**[input.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)** will read the integers only.

For reading `strings` you can use **[next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) or [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)** like this:

```
col1 = input.nextLine();
col2 = input.nextLine();
col3 = input.nextLine();
col4 = input.nextLine();
col5 = input.nextLine();
col6 = input.nextLine();
col7 = input.nextLine();
col8 = input.nextLine();
col9 = input.nextLine();
col10 = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I didnt even notice I had .nextInt, I was trying several variations to get it to work and I guess I forgot I had that in

Comment: @user3037596:- You are welcome! Never mind sometimes even the best commits these things! Happy coding;)

Comment: was this line ok: System.out.println(myArray.asList.reverse(myArray));

Comment: @user3037596:- I would suggest you to run that. Also what is asList ?

Comment: I dunno, saw that as a suggestion somewhere, I was just goofing around actually with the reverse part...it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

`input.nextInt()` is meant for integers only. Hence the problem with Strings.

If you need Strings, you either use next() or nextLine()(for nextLine() the input must be entered with a new line after every input).

Comment: Thanks alot people for the quick responses, I didnt even notice I had .nextInt, I'll give that a try when I get home work